# Stuck on continuity proof (like 8 sheets of A4...) $p_if$ is cont. iff $f$ is cont, $p_i:X\rightarrow X_i$ given by $p_i(a)=a_i$ for $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Let $Y$ be a metric space, let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ where $(X,d)$ is a metric space given by $X=\prod^n_{i=1}X_i$ equipped with the stadard metric ($\max$)

I wish to prove $f$ is continuous iff $\forall i\in\{1,...,n\}$ the function $p_if$ is continuous

Where $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $p_i(a)=a_i$

The $f$ is continuous $\implies p_if$ side is trivial (composition of continuous functions) it is going the other way I am stuck on. The question is quite long and I think is trying to lead me somewhere. Here's what has happened so far:

Proved the open ball in $(X,d)$ is a product of the open balls in $(X_1,d_1),...,(X_n,d_n)$

Proved that a basis of the system of neighborhoods at $a\in X$ consists of all sets of the form $B_1XB_2X...XB_n$ where $B_i\in$ Basis for the system of neighborhoods at $a_i\in X_i$

Proved that the projection $p_i:X\rightarrow X_i$ given by $p_i(a)=a_i$ is continuous

By the way my answers to these are longer than I'd like, if you have a quick two-liner for any of the above please do tell me.

**What have I tried**

Many different definitions of continuity. Like:  (how do I do a curly $B$ in LaTeX?)
$f$ is continuous $\iff$ $\forall B\in\mathbb{B_{f(a)}}$ $f^{-1}(B)$ is a neigh of a.

I've also tried the more standard ball form: $\forall N_{f(a)}\exists M_a : f(M_a)\subset N_{f(a)}$

I've gotten close a few times (I think) and I wil upload pictures of my (unyielding) work so far, I think I'm just missing a simple trick.

I would love a hint more than anything, I know this is "Q&A" not "Q&H" but I'm frustrated enough to ask here, I'd like to get it independently really.

Comment: $\mathscr{B}$? `\mathscr{B}`; $\mathcal{B}$? `\mathcal{B}`. Note $A_1 \times A_2 \times \dotsc \times A_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^n p_k^{-1}(A_k)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I did find that earlier when I was trying to show $f^{-1}(B)$ is a neigh of a. I get $f^{-1}(B)\subset f^{-1}(p^{-1}_i(B))=(f^{-1}p_i^{-1})(B)$ which looks promising, but the subset is on the wrong side. Or (realising what you just wrote) I hit $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(\bigcap^n_{i=1}P_i^{-1}(B))$ and get stuck on how to proceed. Is this the right avenue?

Comment: @DanielFischer using the ball style of continuity I have gotten to: $\prod^n_{i=1}(p_if)(K_{ia})\subset B_\epsilon((f(a))\subset N_{f(a)}$ where the $K_{ia}$ exist from the continuity of $p_if$, this all comes from noticing that for a neigh. $N_{f(a)}\exists\epsilon>0:B_\epsilon(f(a))\subset N_{f(a)}$ then from the previous parts noting: $B_\epsilon(f(a))=\prod^n_{i=1}B_\epsilon((p_if)(a))$ - is that a better road?

Comment: $$f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^n p_k^{-1}B_k\right) = \bigcap_{k=1}^n (p_k\circ f)^{-1}(B_k)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer that's wrong (I did other things yesterday don't worry) consider the function that squares things and a set containing 1 and a set containing -1, it is true that $f(\bigcap^n_{i=1}B_i)\subset\bigcap^n_{i=1}f(B_i)$ only.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh, nevermind, I have proved for $f^{-1}$ they are equal, but for $f$ itself, what I said above holds, can you confirm this (I'm going to press on now, I've got more confidence now!)

Comment: Yes, for $f$ we have $f\left(\bigcap A_k\right) \subset \bigcap f(A_k)$ and generally not equality (but if $f$ is injective, equality holds for all families $A_k$). For $f^{-1}$, we have $f^{-1}\left(\bigcap A_k\right) = \bigcap f^{-1}(A_k)$. Unions commute with $f$ as well as $f^{-1}$.